# What happened to Yuuki at the end of the manga?

Tags: vampire-knight

In chapter 93, Yuuki was shown with Kaname and 2 girls. Are these 2 girls Yuuki and Zero's kids?

What happened to Yuuki when she turned Kaname into a human? Is she dead like when her mother turned Yuuki into a human?

What happened to Zero here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In chapter 93, Yuuki was shown with Kaname and 2 girls. Are these 2 girls Yuuki and Zero's kids?

The two girls, Ai and Ren are daughters of Yuuki & Kaname, and Yuuki & Zero respectively.

> What happened to Yuuki when she turned Kaname into a human? Is she dead like when her mother turned Yuuki into a human?

Actually Yuuki didn't die immediately. Kaname was awoken after 200 years where Yuuki and Zero are not alive. *Vampire Knight Memories* tells the story of when Kaname is asleep.

Comment: how come `The two girls ai and Ren are daughters of yuuki-kaname and yuuki zero respectively` where is this written or mentioned?

Comment: As I said it is mentioned in Vampire Knight Memories